# Maven: test package cannot be a dependency of other test packages?

Tags: java, maven, junit

My project uses maven as the build tool, which works well so far.

I have a test module including all test cases of other modules, which is arranged under test/src/test/java/

[image: test module]

However, when I create another module (let's call it TestB) and let it depend on the module test, all classes/interfaces defined in module test are invisible to the TestB. I wonder because I put all stuff under test/src/test/java but not test/src/main/java.

But if I move classes to test/src/main/java, the JUnit tool will stop working. Any good ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

There's some documentation in the Maven documentation on [how to do this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html).

Basically, it comes down to adding this:

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.6</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <goals>
             <goal>test-jar</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

To your pom.xml, after which you can use the dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.myco.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```